# Node.js で process.env をスタブする方法

Tags: javascript, テスト, mock

`process.env` をテスト用に置き換えたいと考えています。

現状では以下のようにごっそりと置き換えています。もっとスマートな方法はありますでしょうか？

```
describe('test', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.env = process.env;
    process.env = { hoge: 123 };
  });
  afterEach(function() { process.env = this.env; });
  it('works', function() { /* ... */ });
});
```

`function` の場合には Sinon.JS で `sinon.stub(obj, 'method', func)` が良いと思うのですが、`property` の場合にはどうするのが良いのか分かりません。

Comment: タグにsinonを追加しました。

Answer (score 2):

Sinon.JSの[Sandbox API](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#sinon-sandbox)を使うのはどうでしょうか？
以下サンプルコードです。
これだとPATH環境変数だけスタブするというような事が出来ました。

```
var sandbox = require('sinon').sandbox.create();
describe('test', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    sandbox.stub(process.env, "PATH", "hoge");
  });
  afterEach(function() {
    sandbox.restore();
  });
  it('works', function() { /* ... */ });
});
```